# How do you find a JavaScript critical error at a line that does not exist?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How do you find a JavaScript critical error at a line that does not exist?

Visual studio has this error message when I am debugging an aspx file with C# with JavaScript:

```
*JavaScript critical error at line 270, column 317 in     
http://localhost:18159/Applications/Graduate/default.aspx

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error*
```

The problem is that this file is only 246 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at line 270 of the actual rendered HTML output. Do this via the View Source option in your browser, or using a plugin like Firebug or Chrome Developer panel.